# Using looping to get inputs with one line of code

Tags: jquery, html

I am learning jQuery. I am no ninja at it. After reading the [following](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_get.asp) tutorial at W3Schools, I wanted to try something difficult. So I modified their sample a little bit wrote this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
     for(i=1;i<7;i++)              // Getting the values from the input boxes
        {
           var a[i] = $("#test"+i).val();
         }  

   for(i=1;i<7;i++)              //printing the values in the document
        {
           document.write("<p>"+a[i]+"</p>");
         }  
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<p>Name: <input type="text" id="test1" value="Mickey Mouse"></p><br>
<p>Name: <input type="text" id="test2" value="Mickey "></p><br>
<p>Name: <input type="text" id="test3" value="Mouse"></p><br>
<p>Name: <input type="text" id="test4" value="Micse"></p><br>
<p>Name: <input type="text" id="test5" value="Mice"></p><br>
<p>Name: <input type="text" id="test6" value="use"></p><br>

<button>Show Value</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here in the line `var a[i] = $("#test"+i).val();`, is this possible. I mean using "`+`" sign for identifying the id. ?

The code is not working. It should show all the inputs made in the fields on the html page. But it is not showing any response. Is there any mistake I made which jQuery doesn't support?

Comment: For one, you don't want to use document.write after the document is ready.

Comment: then ? How to write on the document ?

Comment: append it to a target element instead. http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Also, when looking for help with a problem, "it doesn't work" doesn't mean anything to us. we need to know what you mean by it doesn't work. what does it not do. what does it do instead. what (if any) errors are appearing in the browser's console(not the statusbar, the actual console that you have to open up.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to declare `a` outside of the for loop as an array. This will allow your code to work as-is, however you will lose all of your html.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var a = [];
        for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) // Getting the values from the input boxes
        {
            a[i] = $("#test" + i).val();
        }

        for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) //printing the values in the document
        {
            document.write("<p>" + a[i] + "</p>");
        }
    });
});
```

To avoid losing all of your html, add a div to your html that will contain the output, for example,

```
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
```

then replace your document.write with `$("#output").append("<p>" + a[i] + "</p>");`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var a = [];
        for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) // Getting the values from the input boxes
        {
            a[i] = $("#test" + i).val();
        }
        $("#output").empty();
        for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) //printing the values in the document
        {
            $("#output").append("<p>" + a[i] + "</p>");
        }
    });
});
```

However, you still have two for loops, you could reduce it to one like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("#output").empty();
        for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) // Getting the values from the input boxes
        {
            $("#output").append("<p>" + $("#test" + i).val() + "</p>");
        }
    });
});
```

That's good, but we're not done yet. $("#output") is a relatively expensive method call, we can reduce to only making it once rather than seven times by caching it in a variable and reusing it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var outputDiv = $("#output").empty();
        for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) // Getting the values from the input boxes
        {
            outputDiv.append("<p>" + $("#test" + i).val() + "</p>");
        }
    });
});
```

Now the code runs quickly and efficiently, however if we ever added another input, we would have to increase the magic number (`7`) by 1. Why not instead just loop over the inputs?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var outputDiv = $("#output").empty();
        // $("input[id^=test]") selects all inputs that have an id that starts with "test"
        $("input[id^=test]").each(function(){
            outputDiv.append("<p>" + this.value + "</p>");
        });
    });
});
```

You could do even more by moving the .append to outside of the each loop, however that will not make a significant difference in this case compared to the additional code it would require.

Comment: u said "$("#output") is a relatively expensive method call, we can reduce to only making it one by caching it in a variable and reusing it:"   can you please explain why? or just refer me to some page.

Comment: Basically, every call to `$()` that has a string as the argument is expensive because jQuery has to determine whether you passed a selector string or html, then handle it appropriately. By caching it, jquery only has to do that once rather than once per input.

Comment: What if i want to save the inputs in an array so that i can process on them later? I am again asking the same question. Is my method `a[i] = $("#test" + i).val();`  valid ?

Comment: does it work? if it worked i'd say it's atleast somewhat valid. Where would that be used?

Comment: suppose i have to do some computations on the input .. there this would be needed.

Answer (score 2):

You could write

```
  var a = [];
  $("button").click(function(){
       $("[id^=test]").each(function(){a[+this.id.slice(-1)]=this.value});
  });
```

Note that you must create the array before you fill it. In your code, it would also have been better to declare the variable `i` with `var i=...`.

Another solution to get all the values in a array, without looping, would be this one :

```
  $("button").click(function(){
    var a = $("[id^=test]").map(function(){return this.value}).get();
  });
```

When you want to add some element to the document, use append :

```
  $('<p>'+a[i]+'</p>').appendTo(document.body);
```

If you want to do all in one go, you may write this :

```
$($("[id^=test]").map(function(i){
      return '<p>value ' + i + '= '+this.value+'</p>'
}).get().join('')).appendTo(document.body);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/pvyYw/)

But there are usually many ways to do a thing with jQuery.

Comment: Your main errors were the absence of declaration of the array a and the use of document.write (don't use it after the document is loaded).

Comment: what does id^=test means ?

Comment: It selects all elements whose id starts with test. [Here's the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Comment: And `+this.id.slice(-1)` extracts the last character of the id and converts it to a number.

Answer (score 1):

To append paragraphs containing the value of each input to the page you can do this  - http://jsfiddle.net/6PQgq/

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $('input').each(function(){
        $('body').append('<p>'+$(this).val()+'</p>');
    });
});
```